Generalization of Bell inequality for N-partite n-level systems
There are generalizations of Bell inequalities for systems of $N$ qubits, see this work
For higher dimensional systems with Hilbert space dimension $d$, we have the following paper:
Bell inequalities for higher dimensional systems
I am looking for a generalization of such inequalities when the system in question is that of N qudits, with each qudit having dimension $d$ (for example, this can include the spatial coordinates and the spin as degrees of freedom for each party). Is there a good reference on how to construct a general Bell inequality in such cases? For instance, the standard CHSH inequality for bi-partite systems with $d=2$, the classical bound and Tsirelson bound are respectively $2$ and $2\sqrt{2}$. How do these bounds change in general with the number of parties $N$ and the Hilbert space dimension $d$ for each party?
CASE OF STUDY: Suppose we have $N$ parties, but only 2 of them (selected arbitrarily) are allowed to measure. In particular, suppose these two parties $A,B$ can only measure spin components $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2$ as quantum operations. The state of each party is defined on a Hilbert space of dimension $d$, which contains both the spatial and spin degrees of freedom $|x,\sigma\rangle$ as a basis. If parties $A,B$ perform spin measurements at each location $x$, they always obtain either $+1$ or $-1$; however the spectrum of $A_1,B_1,A_2,B_2$ is highly degenerate in these eigenvalues because of the spatial degree of freedom.
The question is, for example, what is the classical CHSH bound in that particular case and how does it depend on the dimension $d$ and the number of parties $N$.

did you have a look at https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.2849?

Thanks for the reference. I have trouble to understand the results if in higher dimensional systems, the possible outcomes are highly degenerate, for example, by measuring only spin projections at each spatial location. Do the proofs apply in that case too?

can you be more specific on what you mean? for example, what are "degenerate outcomes" here? Are you referring to a specific part of the notes above?

I refer to the reference in Appendix 1.b (Collins et al.), for arbitrary dimensions. The two parties A and B perform measurements that can carry only values +- 1, say spin components, but they do that on every spatial location "x", therefore for each "x", one obtains always either +1 or -1 (hence degenerate quantum spectrum) in the extended space {|x,spin>}. What is the equivalent CHSH inequality in that case, i.e. the classical bound?

is that yet another paper? I don't see it linked in the post.  Please edit the post to include all references and information relevant to the question at hand. For the general question: there is no unique generalisation of Bell's inequality to higher dimensions. There are multiple possible inequalities each one covering different parts of the boundary of classical behaviours, as discussed in depth in the review above. It just so happens that for 2-2 scenarios (2 1-qubit parties and binary outcomes) there's only one inequality, but that stops being the case as soon as you increase dimensions

Thanks for the comment, I have updated the post. I understand there might be many inequalities, but for the case of study stated above, it suffices.

First of all, you shouldn't confuse the dimension of the quantum state with the number of outcomes used in the Bell inequality. They often coincide, but often they are also completely different.
Secondly, one can in principle obtain all Bell inequalities for a given number of parties, outcomes, and settings, as explained in section II.B of the nonlocality review. However, the complexity of the method is staggering, and in practice you can't study anything other than the simplest scenarios with it. For this reason, when people study the more complex scenarios they do it via some ansatz for which they can find the local and Tsirelson bounds.
For the case of $n$ parties and $k$ outcomes there isn't much known. I'm aware of this paper that finds a family of Bell inequalities for the general case, and this paper that studies in depth the case of 3 parties and $k$ outcomes.
